# How to check source code for forbidden words extGWT

Tags: java, gwt, ant, gxt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to search for a string in files with Ant (make sure certain string isn't found in source files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302019/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-files-with-ant-make-sure-certain-string-isnt-fou)

I am working on a project with a small team (~5 developers) and we would like to ensure that a list of words does not end up in our source code. This code is a extGWT project and we are using an ANT build script to build and deploy our project. We have a text file that has the list of bad words. The build will happen on a linux machine so I have access to find and grep and the like. I can just have the build fail if a bad word is found and we can then do a search of the source code to find where the bad word is located. Any hints on getting this working would be a huge help.

Comment: I'm reminded of an old coding partner who would only name his variables for swears.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4302019

Comment: I was going to suggest that anyone who wants to swear in the code is going to find ways around this check. Then I thought, if there's only 5 people on the project, you can presumably trust them not to try to get around this check. Then I thought, if there's only 5 people on the project, you can presumably trust them not to swear in the first place.

Comment: It's not intentional inclusion of the bad words we are worried about, it is inadvertent inclusions that could potentially problematic. and yes this is a dupe of the post Jason points to, thanks for that.

Comment: Any ideas on how to expand that to search for a list of strings rather than just one string?

Comment: Looking for 'inadvertant' swears seems a little excessive. Are you going to fail a build if there is a variable 'hashiteration'?

Comment: @Jodosh The post Jason and Danny pointed to relies on a regexp, so you can just do `word1|second|hashiteration` to look for those three words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all the comments I received I was able to solve my issue and I thought I would put my full solution here for future reference.

```
<target name="badword-search" description="search for bad words">
        <echo>Doing badword-serach</echo>
        <property name="src.dir" value="src" />
        <property name="search.string" value="\b(word1|word2|word3)\b" />

        <fileset id="existing" dir="${src.dir}">
            <patternset id="files">
                <!-- includes/excludes for your source here -->
            </patternset>
        </fileset>

        <fileset id="matches" dir="${src.dir}">
            <patternset refid="files" />
            <containsregexp expression="${search.string}" casesensitive="false" />
        </fileset>

        <fail message="Found badword in one or more files in '${src.dir}'">
            <condition>
                <resourcecount when="greater" count="0" refid="matches" />
            </condition>
        </fail>
    </target>
```