# How to extract values from a HTML file and use them in ant script for further processing?

Tags: javascript, java, html, xml, ant

In my ANT script i need to read a HTML page which contains a table in it. This table contains list of builds with result 'Pass' & 'Fail'. Pass marked as Green and Fail marked as Red.

Now my Questions:

1. How can i get the build id which is pass & latest?
2. Lets say the build id is 'abc'. How can i call this 'abc' in ant script for
   further processing.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302019/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-files-with-ant-make-sure-certain-string-isnt-fou

Comment: Thank you very much @Maverick