# How can I make my ant build fail if a "debugger" is left in my javascript files?

Tags: javascript, ant, build

Recently I pushed some code all the way to production and just then I noticed a debugger was left in the code. I'd like to catch it early, so I'm looking for a way to add a task to my ant build that would make it fail if a debugger is present (and not commented out). Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302019/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-files-with-ant-make-sure-certain-string-isnt-fou

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific how you notice the debugger in your code? Is a certain enabled macro or code?

Comment: @akr, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger

Comment: Will's reference to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302019/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-files-with-ant-make-sure-certain-string-isnt-fou provides a good answer for this question